# for loop, and url.remove() only affecting every other entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Getting some confusing behaviour when running a for loop and removing entries from a list (cleaning out invalid urls):

```
urls = ['http://a.com/?mail=a@b.com','mailto:a@a.com', 'mailto:a@b.com', 'mailto:a@c.com', 'mailto:a@d.com']

for s in urls:
    if '@' in s and '?' not in s:
        urls.remove(s)

print(urls)
```

The output is:

```
['mailto:a@b.com', 'mailto:a@d.com']
```

It is consistently every other entry, so I'm assuming my understanding of python is not correct.

I looked into list comprehension with Python and ended up with:

```
urls = [s for s in urls if not ('?' not in s and '@' in s)]
```

This does what I want it to.

Is that the best way, can someone explain the behaviour, because I don't get it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, expected output is:['http://a.com/?mail=a@b.com'], formatting is strange on comments, to be clear, the first entry in the list should remain as is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first solution is that you iterate over an object while deleting entries from it. The topic is discussed here for example: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Thanks, that is now clear - I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove from list while iterating over, take a copy and iterate. `urls[:]` takes a copy of `urls` and you iterate over that. This prevents some unexpected situations that occur when iterating through the original list:

```
urls = ['http://a.com/?mail=a@b.com','mailto:a@a.com', 'mailto:a@b.com', 'mailto:a@c.com', 'mailto:a@d.com']

for s in urls[:]:
    if '@' in s and '?' not in s:
        urls.remove(s)

print(urls)
```

But, I would rather prefer the list-comprehension version of yours, that's more concise and pythonic.

Comment: I believe this is a good solution but you should explain it.

Comment: @Cole, How about now? I was in the process of writing explanation. :)

Comment: That's a cool tip, and useful when I need to do a bit more than just remove based on characters - and still having code I can actually read (regardless of how pythonic it might be) :)